# How to have the sidebar open by default when using a toggle switch in R

Tags: r, shiny, toggle

I have created the following shiny App. The App consists of the following parts

import necessary libraies

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinyjs)
```

Next we create the US. Note that we are adding a toggle sidebar option using the material switch function as follows

```
 # Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
 ui <- fluidPage(  
# App title ----
titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
useShinyjs(), navbarPage(materialSwitch(inputId = "toggleSidebar",label = "", 
value = FALSE, status = "success")),
# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
sidebarLayout(div( id ="Sidebar",
# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
sidebarPanel(     
  # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
  sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
              label = "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30))),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
   mainPanel( # Output: Histogram ----
  plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
   )))
```

Next we create a server as follows

```
  # Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
 server <- function(input, output) {
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
   x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
     xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
     main = "Histogram of waiting times")})



    observeEvent(input$toggleSidebar, {
        shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar")
    })}
```

We now run the App.

```
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the App runs, the sidebar containing the slider with the number of bins is collapsed as the sidebar is collapsed by default. The same can be accessed by pressing the toggle switch.

Is it possible to have the sidebar open by default and then collapse the same when the toggle switch is clicked

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toggle`s `condition` argument to determine if the sidebar should be shown or hidden:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  useShinyjs(), navbarPage(materialSwitch(inputId = "toggleSidebar",label = "", 
                                          value = TRUE, status = "success")),
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(div( id ="Sidebar",
                     # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                     sidebarPanel(     
                       # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
                       sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                                   label = "Number of bins:",
                                   min = 1,
                                   max = 50,
                                   value = 30))),

                # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                mainPanel( # Output: Histogram ----
                           plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
                )))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")})

  observeEvent(input$toggleSidebar, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar", condition = input$toggleSidebar)
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Oh no. am afraid this gives the same output. The sidebar should be visible when the app starts up and then when we use the toggle switch, it should collapse

Comment: The sidebar is visible on startup. Please copy the entire code provided above and try again.

Comment: Neat. Thank you. is the addition of shinywidgets the key.

Comment: You are using `materialSwitch` which is part of the `library(shinyWidgets)`.